# How can I get to the RootViewController using pushcontroller?

Tags: iphone, xcode

By below code I am moving to RootViewController from firstView.

```
RootViewController *controller = [[RootViewController alloc] 
                              initWithNibName:@"RootView" bundle:nil];
[self.navigationController popToRootViewControllerAnimated:YES];      
[controller release];
```

Now, how can I move to RootViewController from the last View using push, but not with pop?????
 We have to change pop to push?
 Can anyone help in suggesting the code for this ?????

Answer (score 0):

`popToRootViewControllerAnimated` will pop to the beginning of the stack.

```
myRoot -> firstView -> secondView -> thirdView
```

If you were to use `popToRootViewControllerAnimated` in `thirdView`, it will pop to `myRoot`.

Comment: Can't we do using PushToRootViewController?

Comment: I want myRoot->firstView->SecondView->ThirdView->myRoot from the thirdView. I am going using pop, but can I go using push concept?

Comment: PushToRootViewController doesnt exist, so you cant use it. Also, pushing to myRoot from thirdView wouldnt make sense, but you can always init like any other view and push to it. Not use-friendly though, you will confuse users and myRoot will now have a back button that pops to thirdView.

Comment: Or can we do using [self.navigationController pushViewController:controller animated:YES];

Comment: Yes, but like I explained previously, myRoot will now have a back button that will pop to thirdView.

Comment: Because I used the popToRootViewControllerAnimated, it is working fine. But when I swipe at the right hand side, the view is coming from left hand side instead of coming from right hand side? Did you get me my friend?

Comment: push a view animates to going to the right, pop animates a view to the left.

Comment: Yup, but in the lastView I used popToRootViewControllerAnimated, and the RootViewController is coming from right side instead of left side?

Comment: but it is sliding from left...sorry to mistake